# Select multiple keys and values from a NESTED column

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-analytics-firebase

I'm linking Google Analytics 4 events into a BigQuery table.
I can retrieve data just based on one key, but how do I get the value stored in another key in the same record as that key?

In specific, I want to **rank the number of views by the name of the article**, and then provide the author's name in a separate column as a supplementary data (the author's name is stored in the same record with a different key in a nested column).

### Environment

Google Analytics 4
Set up events in Google Tag Manager

The table schema looks like this, with keys such as `article_name` `author_name` in `event_params.key` and the value you want to get in `event_params.value.string_value`.

[image]

And the table preview looks like this:

```
+-----+------------+-----------------+--------------+------------------+---------------------------------+
| Row | event_date | event_timestamp | event_name   | event_params.key | event_params.value.string_value |
+-----+------------+-----------------+--------------+------------------+---------------------------------+
| 1   | 20201127   | 160394324324231 | view_article | article_name     | My Article A                    |
|     |            |                 |              | author_name      | Author A                        |
|     |            |                 |              | random key1      | random value1                   |
|     |            |                 |              | random key2      | random value2                   |
| 2   | 20201127   | 160394324324112 | view_article | article_name     | My Article B                    |
|     |            |                 |              | author_name      | Author B                        |
|     |            |                 |              | random key1      | random value3                   |
|     |            |                 |              | random key2      | random value4                   |
 ...
+-----+------------+-----------------+--------------+------------------+---------------------------------+
```

### What I tried

Was able to pull off the article ranking itself, without the author name.

```
#standardSQL

WITH _data AS (
    SELECT 
        value.string_value AS article_name 
    FROM 
        `my-new-project.analytics_000000000.events_*`, 
        UNNEST(event_params) 
    WHERE 
        event_name = 'article_view'
)

SELECT
    article_name,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM
    _data
GROUP BY
    1
ORDER BY
    2 DESC
```

Result:

```
+-----+--------------+-----+
| Row | article_name | cnt |
+-----+--------------+-----+
| 1   | My Article A | 20  |
| 2   | My Article D | 18  |
| 3   | My Article C | 11  |
| 4   | My Article B | 9   |
  ...
+-----+--------------+-----+
```

I wanted to add a column for `author_name` next to `article_name` here, so I thought it would be a good idea to use CASE WHEN.
But as it turns out, the `author_name` will all be null, which probably means it is treated as a separate record.

```
#standardSQL

WITH _data AS (
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN key = 'article_name' THEN value.string_value
        END AS article_name,
        CASE WHEN key = 'author_name' THEN value.string_value
        END AS author_name
    FROM 
        `my-new-project.analytics_000000000.events_*`, 
        UNNEST(event_params) 
    WHERE 
        key = 'article_name'
)

SELECT
    article_name,
    MAX(author_name),
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM
    _data
GROUP BY
    1
ORDER BY
    3 DESC
```

Result:

```
+-----+--------------+-------------+-----+
| Row | article_name | author_name | cnt |
+-----+--------------+-------------+-----+
| 1   | My Article A | null        | 20  |
| 2   | My Article D | null        | 18  |
| 3   | My Article C | null        | 11  |
| 4   | My Article B | null        | 9   |
  ...
+-----+--------------+-------------+-----+
```

When I GROUP BY with `author_name` in a descending order, the author's name appears correctly, but this time the `article_name` is all null. Is it possible to have both article_name and author_name in the same record, and have the author name next to article name in the same ranking result?

Comment: seems like you are fltering out 'article_authors , how about you change your where clause in cte to `WHERE key IN ( 'article_name' , 'author_name')` ?

Comment: I think the reason why I get null for either column may be because I am UNNESTing the column, so I tried SELECTing them using dots without UNNESTing - like `e.event_params.key.article_name` (e being the alias for my table name). But BigQuery returns :
>Cannot access field key on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64, float_value FLOAT64, ...>>> at [5:24]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for a sub-select solution:

```sql
SELECT
   (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'article_name') AS article_name,
   (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'author_name') AS author_name,
count(1) as cnt
FROM 
  `my-new-project.analytics_000000000.events_*`
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Comment: Welcome! If you'd like more explanation for what's going on in the query let me know.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you are fltering out 'article_authors , how about you change your where clause in cte to WHERE key IN ( 'article_name' , 'author_name')

so your query should look like this :

```
#standardSQL

WITH _data AS (
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN key = 'article_name' THEN value.string_value
        END AS article_name,
        CASE WHEN key = 'author_name' THEN value.string_value
        END AS author_name
    FROM 
        `my-new-project.analytics_000000000.events_*`, 
        UNNEST(event_params) 
    WHERE 
        key IN ( 'article_name' , 'author_name') 
)

SELECT
    article_name,
    MAX(author_name),
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM
    _data
GROUP BY
    1
ORDER BY
    3 DESC
```

Comment: Thank you eshirvana, I tried your query but it still gives me a table result where only either one of article_name or author_name appears in each record, and the other one remains null. And if I COUNT(*) this and GROUP BY this based on article_name, I still can't see an author_name next to it. Is there a way to have those two values in a same record as two different non-null columns?

Comment: what is the output of _data cte  from my query above?

Comment: it gives me an out put like this where I have null for author_name. If I GROUP BY with author_name, I get a ranking of author_name but with null for article_name columns. So presumably I am creating records with only either one of article_name or author_name.

```
+-----+--------------+-------------+-----+
| Row | article_name | author_name | cnt |
+-----+--------------+-------------+-----+
| 1   | My Article A | null        | 20  |
| 2   | My Article D | null        | 18  |
| 3   | My Article C | null        | 11  |
  ...
+-----+--------------+-------------+-----+
```

Comment: Oh I can't make a code view in the comment section.. but it's basically the same as I describe in the last part of my original question with "Result:".